# Converting SVG to PNG loses styling elements

Tags: javascript, reactjs, svg

In ReactJS I have an interface that allows a user to make customizations to an SVG block. There are three components within the SVG: a rectangle (for background), text, and an SVG path image.

The SVG is rendered as such, with props coming from a parent component's state:

```
renderLogo() {
    let style = this.props.logoStyle;

    return (
        <svg width="300" height="100" className={"logo"} xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">

            <g>
                <rect id="background" x="0" y="0" width="300" height="100" rx={style.bgBorderRadius} ry={style.bgBorderRadius} 
                fill={style.backgroundColor} stroke="2" />
            </g>

            <svg
             xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
             width={style.iconSize}
             height={style.iconSize}
             viewBox="0 0 1000 1000"
                x="10"
                y="13"
             id="svg4272">
            <g>
                {this.renderIcon()}
            </g>
             </svg>

        <g>             
            <text 
                x="90" 
                y="58" 
                fontSize={style.fontSize}
                fontFamily={style.fontFamily}
                fontWeight={style.fontWeight}
                stroke={style.fontStrokeColor}
                strokeWidth={style.fontStrokeWidth}
                fill={style.fontColor}
                textAlign="right"
                >{style.companyName}</text>
          </g>          
        </svg>
    );
}

render() {
    let style = this.props.logoStyle;
    return (
        <div className="logo-preview">
            {this.renderLogo()}

            <canvas id="canvas" width="900" height="300"></canvas>  
            <button className="btn btn-success" onClick={this.onDownload}>Download</button>

        </div>
    );
}
```

The button triggers function onDownload() which then attempts to paint to the #canvas, and then launches a download of the PNG

```
onDownload() {

    var svg = document.querySelector('svg.logo');

// This function is from here that I hoped would help with the issue: https://github.com/lukehorvat/computed-style-to-inline-style 
    var computedToInline = require('computed-style-to-inline-style');
    computedToInline(svg, true);


    var canvas = document.querySelector('canvas');

     var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
     var data = (new XMLSerializer()).serializeToString(svg);

    var DOMURL = window.URL || window.webkitURL || window;

     var img = new Image();
     var svgBlob = new Blob([data], {type: 'image/svg+xml;charset=utf-8'});
     var url = DOMURL.createObjectURL(svgBlob);

      img.onload = () => {
        // clip and scale up
        ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, 300, 100, 0, 0, 900, 300);
        DOMURL.revokeObjectURL(url);

        var imgURI = canvas
            .toDataURL('image/png')
            .replace('image/png', 'image/octet-stream');

          this.triggerDownload(imgURI);

      };

      img.src = url;
}

triggerDownload(imgURI) {
    console.log("triggerDownload");
    var evt = new MouseEvent('click', {
        view: window,
        bubbles: false,
        cancelable: true
    });


    var a = document.createElement('a');
    a.setAttribute('download', 'imageFile.png');
    a.setAttribute('href', imgURI);
    a.setAttribute('target','_blank');

    a.dispatchEvent(evt);
}
```

The issue:

When drawing it to the canvas, the icon is rendering correctly, but the background (SVG component ) is removed, and the  attributes (ex. font-family) are defaulting to Helvetica Neue instead of the selected fonts / attributes. This carries into the download file.

EDIT:

As mentioned one of the issues is the fonts, and these do come from Google. From the link provided in the comments, it seems I need to reference these via data URIs inline. I have encoded them using FontSquirrel.com, but I am unsure how to reference them in the SVG inline, in React:

```
@font-face {
font-family: 'pacificoregular';
src: url(data:application/font-woff2;charset=utf-8;base64,d09GMgA...),
     url(data:application/font-woff;charset=utf-8;base64,d09Grg...) format('woff');
font-weight: normal;
font-style: normal;
}
```

I tried inserting this into an element in `<defs><style>...</style></defs>` but it errors. I tried converting to React syntax like so, but it also fails:

```
<style>
@fontFace {
fontFamily: 'pacificoregular';
src: url(data:application/font-woff2;charset=utf-8;base64,d09GMgA...),
     url(data:application/font-woff;charset=utf-8;base64,d09Grg...) format('woff');
fontWeight: normal;
fontStyle: normal;
}
</style>
```

How can I reference the font inline to the SVG if I cannot use @font-face? Or is there actually a proper way to utilize @font-face here?

EDIT 2:

Removed `<def>` tags, and used `@fontFace{}` syntax:

Error when attempting this syntax I receive a syntax error that is complaining about the ":" after 'fontFamily' in:

```
@fontFace {
fontFamily: 'pacificoregular';
...
}
```

Comment: You'd have to convert the fonts to data URL so that their data is internal to the SVG file.

Comment: Thanks for linking that thread, I hadn't come across that one yet. I'm setting out down that path, and will report back! Thanks again for the tip

Comment: Hi Rob, I did some research into converting the fonts to data URI so that they are internal to the SVG file, but am facing some issues referencing that data URI inline. I edited my post at the bottom to update with some of what I've tried. Any ideas here? I could not find any React-specific examples, and I'm afraid that the React syntax needs (removing hyphenated words, replacing with camelCase) is playing a role here syntactically

Comment: You put @fontFace in style tags, defs is not required. Your open and close tags are misordered anyway.

Comment: Whoops, I typed that block by hand in the editor. Removed the <defs> altogether now, but I'm still unable to execute the code. it errors like so (Edited the bottom of the post because code formatting wasn't working well in the comment

Comment: Errors with what message? Where's your react code that's creating this error message?

Comment: it's an error coming from the node module build (webpack): 

ERROR in ./src/components/logo-preview.js
Module build failed: SyntaxError: Unexpected token, expected } 

(The unexpected token is referring to the ":" after fontFamily)

Comment: it's '@font-face' not '@font-family'

Comment: Gosh, so sorry - all over the place with these typos right now. Yes, I used @fontFace{} (also tried @font-face{}) and inside of the curly brackets I have the paramter 'font-family' (also tried fontFamily) which is attempting to initiate the web font. It is with this internal reference of fontFamily that brings the syntax issue